# Copying SQLite database from assets folder issue

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Can someone point me in the right direction. I am able to create an empty database in /data/data/mypacket/databases but i cant copy my database from the assets folder? Any suggestions? Thanks for the help

CODE:

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.OutputStream; 

import android.content.Context; 
import android.database.SQLException; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; 
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper; 
import android.util.Log; 

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{ 
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window 
//destination path (location) of our database on device 
private static String DB_PATH = "";  
private static String DB_NAME ="MyDatabase";// Database name 
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;  
private final Context mContext; 

public DataBaseHelper(Context context)  
{ 
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version 
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"; 
    this.mContext = context; 
}    

public void createDataBase() throws IOException 
{ 
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets 

    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase(); 
    if(!mDataBaseExist) 
    { 
        this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        this.close(); 
        try  
        { 
            //Copy the database from assests 
            copyDataBase(); 
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created"); 
        }  
        catch (IOException mIOException)  
        { 
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase"); 
        } 
    } 
} 
    //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name 
    private boolean checkDataBase() 
    { 
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME); 
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists()); 
        return dbFile.exists(); 
    } 

    //Copy the database from assets 
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException 
    { 
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
        int mLength; 
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0) 
        { 
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength); 
        } 
        mOutput.flush(); 
        mOutput.close(); 
        mInput.close(); 
    } 

    //Open the database, so we can query it 
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException 
    { 
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath); 
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS); 
        return mDataBase != null; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public synchronized void close()  
    { 
        if(mDataBase != null) 
            mDataBase.close(); 
        super.close(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
 09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    ... 11 more
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099): Caused by: java.lang.Error: Error copying database
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at com.petermihaylov.scjajavaexamquestions.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:56)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at com.petermihaylov.scjajavaexamquestions.TestAdapter.createDatabase(TestAdapter.java:25)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    at com.petermihaylov.scjajavaexamquestions.TrueAndFalse.testasd(TrueAndFalse.java:25)
    09-03 02:22:32.459: E/AndroidRuntime(19099):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: consider mLength in long just becuase of the gettting the long value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem is this:

Since Android Studio uses the new Gradle-based build system, you should be putting assets/ inside of the source sets example myproject/src/main/assets/.

I created my own assets folder and put it where Eclipse usually puts it... which caused all these problems for me.

Comment: You must have mentioned that you were using 'Android Studio'. Since your problem is solved using the method you mentioned here, so, it would be better if you accept it as answer.

Comment: I can only accept my own answer after 24h from posting it. I was not aware that android studio would be the cause of the problem and though I had an error in my code.

Answer (score 2):

A few pointers:

- Check that the file `DB_NAME` is present in the app's "assets" folder (instead of in the "raw" folder).
- If the asset file extension is ".gz", the extension will be removed.
- The asset file should not be bigger than 1MB. If that's the case, try to compress it and decompress it to the database folder.
- Check that the path to `outFileName` exists before copying the file (i.e. `new File(outFileName).getParentFile().mkdirs();`
- Check the `DB_PATH` is properly built depending on the API version.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728):

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2){
    DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";         
}
else
{
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
}
```

Additionally, don't forget to create the `android_metadata` table, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5799920/2050333).

Comment: I was using android studio to create my project and there was no Assets folder. Maybe i need to look into that and make sure its in the correct location/name.
There is no file extention, DB is smaller than 1MB DB path is build and places an empty DB in the correct location. The only thing left should be making sure that there is nothing wrong with my assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to copy from assets database folder to external storage folder.
File needs to be under assets\databases folder.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;

public class Options extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.options);
    }            

    public void backupDatabase(View v) throws IOException {                 
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null)
        {
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp");
            if (dir.exists()) {
                //dir.delete();
            }
            else {
                dir.mkdir();
            }

            String fromPath = "";
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 4.2){
                fromPath = getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/" + "wl.db";         
            }
            else
            {
                fromPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/" + "wl.db";
            }

            String toPath = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/wl.db";

            fileCopy(new File(fromPath), new File(toPath));

            //This is to refresh the folders in Windows USB conn.
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp" }, null, null);         
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { toPath }, null, null);         
        }                   
    }

    public void fileCopy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```