# How to use a database available in asset with ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a database file in **assets** folder, when user install this program, in the first time program launcher I will copy database from **assets** to **databases** of program

This is my code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "data.db";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/************************************************
 * Suggested Copy/Paste Done
 ************************************************/

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    createDataBase();
}

public void createDataBase(){
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!dbExist){
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    String outFileName = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
    File f = new File(outFileName);
    f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    f.createNewFile();
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

I check **databases** folder in the device and see that it has **data.db** file but this file has not table.

The code where I use to copy data have running.

Why **data.db** is wrong ?

---

```
UPDATED:

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "english")
public class Topic {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "id")
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "title")
    private String title;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "question")
    private String question;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "answer")
    private String answer;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "audio_url")
    private String audioUrl;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "local_url")
    private String localUrl;

    public Topic() {
    }
}
CREATE TABLE `english` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `title` NVARCHAR,
    `question`  NVARCHAR,
    `answer`    NVARCHAR,
    `audio_url` NVARCHAR,
    `local_url` NVARCHAR
);
```

Comment: Did you set up the original db file correctly?   See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5799920/420594 regarding android_metadata

Comment: @drhr, pls see my config in model file and when I make database use sql command ?

Comment: I have information is all command work success when I put data.db override to databases folder by manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When

```
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
```

is called a **data.db** have been create. so that `onCreate` will be not call.
you shouldn't put `createDataBase` here.

I think you can put it to **getWritableDatabase** or **getDao** function.

Comment: Thanks, I put that function to get*Dao function and program is worked